# Perforce like GUI client for git

Tags: git, user-interface, perforce

Is there any GUI client for git similar to Perforce? I feel comfortable to work with files than change list. The way git shows things are commit based and it is not that intuitive. Working with Perforce GUI client is very intuitive as I am working with files - P4 gives emphasis to files (at least in GUI).

I don't want git cola or other GUI git clients that gives emphasis to commit history / changelist. I am searching for client that works on file basis.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Even if something like this exists, it's going to horribly break your brain when it comes to thinking in Git. Git is based on changesets to the tree, not on files.

Comment: Contrary to popular opinion, git is in fact [*not* based on changesets](http://gitmanual.org/gitglossary.html#def_changeset); internally it's a [content-addressable file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)#Data_structures). Still, it's unlikely that one will find a git GUI that will replicate the perforce workflow, so it's better to migrate to the git way of doing things. Give it a chance, you might like it. :)

Comment: If you go the file route, you understand you'll be mostly fighting against your tool rather than working with it, right?

Answer (score 3):

You should try SmartGit, it is free for non commercial use and run on almost every operating system.

SmartGit will allow you to work based on changes but also will give you a fil explorer where you are going to have a mix.

Comment: SmartGit is nice but I prefer open source. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

I have used perforce for many years. There is no good version control gui as perforce, never found any one. Including any known git client.

background: I have used clearcase, cvs, subversion, git.... version system along 10+ years dev.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what operating system you are working on, but if you happen to be working on Mac OS X you might want to try Atlassian's Source Tree http://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview

Like SmartGit, it is free, works with changes (commit history), and has a file explorer view with diff support.

Answer (score -1):

Use [SourceTree](http://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree/overview), Its the best.